# Configure connection to mongodb for querying only

Tags: 8, database

We have an external mongodb instance and we need to query data from it and bring it to Drupal 8 site.

On shell this is how we connect (mongodb is running in a different container than drupal)
`mongo --host docker_mongo --ssl --sslCAFile=/etc/ssl/mongodb-cert.crt`

Adding the following at settings.php does not work and status report shows "No database aliases found in settings. Did you actually configure your settings ?"

```
$configureMongoDb = function (array $settings): array {
  $settings['mongodb'] = [
    'clients' => [
      // Client alias => connection constructor parameters.
      'mymongo' => [
        'uri' => 'mongodb://docker_mongo:27017',
        'uriOptions' => ['ssl=true&sslCAFile=/etc/ssl/mongodb-cert.crt'],
        'driverOptions' => [],
      ],
    ],
    'databases' => [
      // Database alias => [ client_alias, database_name ].
      'tutorial2' => ['mymongo', 'tutorial2'],
    ],
  ];

  return $settings;
};
```

Could anyone suggest how to connect to a mongodb instance?

Cross-posting this question at [drupal-mongodb](https://www.drupal.org/project/mongodb/issues/3018098#comment-12881727) issue as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set a function in settings.php to define the connection. The documentation lists this as an example:

https://fgm.github.io/mongodb/install/#settings-configuration

```
// In sites/default/settings.local.php.
$settings['mongodb'] = [
  'clients' => [
    // Client alias => connection constructor parameters.
    'default' => [
      'uri' => 'mongodb://localhost:27017',
      'uriOptions' => [],
      'driverOptions' => [],
    ],
  ],
  'databases' => [
    // Database alias => [ client_alias, database_name ]
    'default' => ['default', 'drupal'],
    'keyvalue' => ['default', 'keyvalue'],
    'logger' => ['default', 'logger'],
  ],
];
```

Comment: Irrespective of where we put this, the status report shows that "No database aliases found in settings. Did you actually configure your settings ?" So something is off

Comment: Thanks, I had another issue as pecl install mongodb was not installing ssl which caused failure to connect with mongoldb